# Scheduled TFS 2008 builds not running

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

2 scheduled builds are triggered to run at 9:30(ET) and 10:30(ET) in TFS 2008 so that offshore team(In India), can validate it, their morning(IST).
Both builds are scheduled to run every weekday and Sunday except Friday.

They were running fine up until last couple of days. Now they won't trigger on their own even though source code has changed after the last build. Manual builds and other CI builds are working fine.

I have verified the trigger time in DB also and it shows correct scheduled time.

Any idea what could've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I reset the build service and it probably set things back to order. Both builds ran at their scheduled time today. The thing that I'm still skeptical about is why the build service was working fine for manual builds or CI builds.